# Are heading elements block or inline elements?

Tags: html

Is it correct to change the color of text inside an H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, or H6 element? Are they block-level elements?

For example:

```
<h1><span style="color:#ABAB">#500</span> Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

They are block elements.

If you look at the HTML 4.01 strict [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ENTITY % heading "H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">

<!ENTITY % block
     "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
      BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">
```

So, they are all defined as `%heading` entities, which in turn are part of the `%block` entities.

As for the question regarding if you can change the color - that's just styling and is fine, though I would do so in a CSS file, not inline:

```css
H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6 {
   color: #ccccc;
}
```

Comment: i liked the way you have added html DTD to explain the answer.GR8

Comment: I was just trying to keep the example simple so used inline CSS. I did try some googling first but I couldn't find my answer from skimming  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5

Comment: @Chris S - no problem. I can only go on what is in the question though ;)

Comment: Great answer btw and it's interesting they've got tokens for categories of other elements inside the block definition

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the correct way, if you want to use inline CSS. Otherwise, use a `class` attribute say:

```
<h1 class="title"><span>#500</span> Hello world</h1>
```

Now the CSS is:

```css
h1.title span {
   color: #ababab;
}
```

Again, yes `<h1>` to `<h6>` are block-level elements.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to find out whether an element is a block-level or inline element is to put a border around it.

HTML

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<span>Span</span>
```

CSS

```css
h1 {
   border: 2px solid green;
}

span {
   border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

More examples on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonkec/g2Vj7/2/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all headers are block-level elements.

On another note, `#ABAB` is not a valid color.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `span` within a h1 tag is allowed. As you can see on the [W3C Reference page for the h1 tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/h1.html):

> Permitted contents: phrasing content

And phrasing content is normal text as well as your `span` element (and several other elements as can be seen on this [reference page for phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasingelem).

Oh yeah, and the heading tags are block elements.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is first to create a CSS style in a stylesheet file.

```css
h1 {
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Color alters font color, not background color, so technically it's equally correct.  However, doing it that way means that for every header you want with this style you must specify a span tag inside like you've done.

Better solution if you want to always have it in effect for h1 tags might be to include a stylesheet with the following code:

```
h1 {
  color: #ABABAB
}
```