# php - save a .html file formatted

Tags: php, html, file, format, save

This is my problem:
I have my html document where I send via ajax two values:
"id" and "a html string"

```
<div class="myClass"><h1 class="myClass">this is my html string </h1></div>
```

I receive this data in my .php file where I save the data in a .html file:

ajax code:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var string = $(".htmlString").html();
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { 
                    ID: "correctID",
                    htmlString: string
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('error');
                }   
            }); 
        });
```

php code:

```
if ($_POST['id'] == "correctID") {

    $fileLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/www/file.html";
    $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
    $content = $_POST['htmlString'];
    fwrite($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
}
```

the output .html file content is like:

```
<div class=\"myClass\"><h1 class=\"myClass\">
```

The **PROBLEM** as you see is the "\" before the quotes:

How can I save my file in a correct html format?

```
<div class="myClass"><h1 class="myClass">
```

Thanks a lot,  was looking and I found DOMDocument::saveHTML but I could not use it, Im very new at PHP.., I really need the classes in my html file.

Comment: Just a side note: as [`h1` is a block element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4041820/2088851), you probably do not need to insert it in a `div` (with the same class moreover).

Comment: yeah I know that, thats jus for the example, thanks @Voitcus

Comment: A first thing to do would be to var_dump($_POST) to make sure it doesn't contain the quotes. This would tell you whether the error is from js or php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is magic quotes, turn it off by using a `.htaccess` file and placing the following directive init.

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Also to save your file you can do with one line using

```
$file_content;
file_put_contents("filename.html", $file_content);
```

Comment: where I put the .htaccess file? in the root? or in the path where I save my .html file? @DevZer0

Comment: you can have it in the root or the same level as the script file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by magic_quotes_gpc.

2 possible solutions:

- Disable magic_quotes_gpc
- call stripslashes on `$_POST['htmlString']