# Forcing site-title and site-text in one line.

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the site text right next to site-title. My code right know is

```
<p>

<block><div style="background-color:#993383; color:#ffffff; font-style: normal; ">
<span class="nowrap"><h3 id="site-title"><b>TEXT GOES HERE</b></h3></span> <span class="nowrap"><h5 id="site-text"> TEXT GOES HERE</h5></span>
     </div></block>
    </p>
```

Im not sure if the code `class="nowrap"` is correct, so i'm hoping you can help me out!

Comment: and the code for the nowrap css?

Comment: Why not just using display:inline for the h3 elements?

Comment: You should remove bogus markup like `<block>` as well as markup and styling that irrelevant to the problem at hand (like color settings here) and, most importantly, include the *relevant* code.

Comment: what i understand you are trying to make them in one line by placing 'block level' element inside, 'inline'. Which not right way to do. block level element is always block whether you place it inside inline element or not. you can fix it - check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats inside your `.nowrap` class. You can make text side by side in many ways like,

```
.nowrap
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/NPJb9/)

if you are wondering why? text is occupying two lines not one. The reason is `h3` is a block level element so it breaks the line. In order to show them side by side Via CSS you can do by adding `display: inline-block`.

[Are H1,H2,H3,H4 tags block or inline elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041820/are-h1-h2-h3-h4-tags-block-or-inline-elements)