# How do you prevent header tags from stretching across the body width

Tags: html

I have some header links.  [Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxwe1gpo/)

```
<a href="#"><h3>Some header link</h3></a>
<a href="#"><h3>Another link</h3></a>
```

The problem is that the clickable link area stretches across the page and doesn't just end where the text ends.  So if the user clicks the whitespace to the right of a link, it still links them to that page.

Now, this is an interesting constraint but is there a purely HTML solution?  I'd like avoid CSS if possible but if it's the only way to do it, then so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 are [heading entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041820/are-h1-h2-h3-h4-tags-block-or-inline-elements) which are part of the block elements.

To make them inline - try
`display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/gxwe1gpo/2/

```
h3{
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Looks like CSS is the only way to go.  Thank you.

Comment: @noblerare glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue myself.  But I didn't want to inline the Header Element.

So an easy solution for me was to place the header tags around the link:

```
<body>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Some link somewhere</a>
    </h3>
</body>
```

Instead of:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">
        <h3>Some link somewhere</h3>
    </a>
</body>
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rLtm4154/

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by the `h3` element. And the only way to solve that is by `CSS`. its easy, just use this instead

```
<body>
    <a href="#"><h3 style="display: inline;">Some link somewhere</h3></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like CSS is the only way to go. Thank you.