# Using 'auto' on block element 'h1'

Tags: html, css

According to [Are H1,H2,H3,H4 tags block or inline elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041820/are-h1-h2-h3-h4-tags-block-or-inline-elements)

> `h1, h2, etc` are block elements

I am trying to center an `h1`, but `margin: 0 auto` does not work.

This confuses me because according to [What is the meaning of `auto` value in a CSS property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471850/what-is-the-meaning-of-auto-value-in-a-css-property)

> a block element with `margin: 0 auto` will have the left and right
>   margins increased until it becomes centered along the y-axis of the viewport.

```html
<h1 style="margin: 0 auto">Is this centered?</h1>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: with them being block elements, its 100% width, not the width of the text.

Comment: downvoted because?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote you reference with regards to `margin: auto` applies only in the case where you specify the width of a block element, since block elements by default will take up 100% of width. Therefore you should use the css `text-align` property in this case. (`text-align: center`).

Answer (score 0):

With them being block elements, their width is 100%, not the width of the text. You should just use `text-align: center`.

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Is this centered?</h1>
```